# air of something

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Fay assumed an ***air of innocence***. ([Source](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/assume))
>
> He assumed an ***air of concern***. ([Source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/assume?q=assume))

What does "air of something" mean in these contexts? I suppose it is generally used with the verb "assume"

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/air#English) states:

> 4. A feeling or sense.

It is the same meaning as in:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

Comment: Thank you I wonder if these sentence still makes sense without "air". For example: "Apparently, this user prefers to keep mystery about them." / "She assumed concern."

Comment: I thought it was 'presumption of innocence'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: You are right, I was wrong.